# Rigify Plugin's generated Rig Handles are not positioned the same as the Armature and Mesh

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, rigify

[image: The Rig Handles are far away]

I already applied both of the Mesh and Armature's Transformations (Location, Rotation and Scale).

Pressing the "Generate Rig" Button after adjusting the Armature to fit the Mesh Model results to the image above.

[image: Object Data Properties tab]

Animating the model is impossible with handles far away from Armature and Mesh. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the origin of the model is where the armature has been placed.

If so, select the character, press shift C to center the 3D cursor, right click and choose "set origin to 3D cursor.

Check also if model or armature has some delta transform, and zero them out.

[image]

Comment: Pressed "Shift+C" then "set origin to 3D cursor". Transform and Delta Transform is already zeroed out. It seems to me that the origin point relocates whenever I generate the rig.

Comment: I think you should upload the file, is there any animation data going on?

Comment: I think there is none as I haven't started animating. Here is the blend file. https://dropmefiles.com/BlX5g

Comment: I don't know exactly where this location data remained in memory (it can be even an intended functionality), but after generating the rig press Alt G to reset the location. At this point if you delete the rig and generate again it will show up in the correct location.